# Pyside2 - qml returns an empty window

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I am trying to use QML with pyside2 but am running in some issues.
I create a simple example to show the issue I am having.
I made a new qml project in Qt Design Studio and am trying to load the qml file in pyside2 but when I run the script, it returns an empty window.

I tried to move the qml at the same level as my main.py but am getting the same results.
my tree structure looks like this.

[image]

this is the content of my main.py

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
import sys

path = 'qmlTest01/qmlTest01.qml'
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
view = QQuickView()
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)

view.setSource(url)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am getting an empty window like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

I made a repo with this example:
https://bitbucket.org/aespid/tests/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your project structure is as follows:

```
├── main.py
└── qmlTest01
    ├── imports
    │   ├── qmlTest01
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── QtQuick
    │       └── ...
    ├── qmlTest01.qml
    ├── qmlTest01.qmlproject
    ├── qtquickcontrols2.conf
    └── Screen01.ui.qml
```

And in your imports you use:

```
import qmlTest01 1.0
// ...
```

but nowhere do you indicate where that library is, but in the case of the second image you must be running the .qmlproject from QtCreator that reads the following configuration:

```
/* File generated by Qt Creator */

import QmlProject 1.1

Project {
    mainFile: "qmlTest01.qml"

    /* ... */

    Files {
        filter: "qmldir"
        directory: "."
    }

    Environment {
        QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_CONF: "qtquickcontrols2.conf"
        QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR: "1"
    }

    /* List of plugin directories passed to QML runtime */
    importPaths: [ "imports" ]

    /* Required for deployment */
    targetDirectory: "/opt/qmlTest01"
}
```

Where it is observed that indicates the route of the import of other modules.

### Solution:

The solution is to set some environment variables with os.environ() and the path of the "imports" folder using addImportPath() of QQmlEngine:

```
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView


if __name__ == "__main__":

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_CONF"] = os.path.join(
        current_dir, "qmlTest01", "qtquickcontrols2.conf"
    )
    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    import_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "qmlTest01", "imports")
    view.engine().addImportPath(import_path)

    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "qmlTest01", "qmlTest01.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    view.setSource(url)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I have another question
When I add a timeline, I am getting the same blank window again.
Somehow, it can't import the module QtQuick.Timeline 1.0

Comment: @aespid Where is this module? I don't see it in your files nor is it part of the standard QML module

Comment: I committed my changes, but I suspect that the timeline module isn't available in python.
I just started to use qml, so I will most likely have a bunch of questions. lol

Comment: @aespid I do not understand you, If it is a module written in C++ then you must compile it (obviously you must have Qt installed with the same version that PySide2 was compiled) and copy the .dlls/.so and qml in predetermined places where PySide2 is installed